# GetILGenerator method is not supported by MethodBuilder

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to generate generic method via `Reflection` API. Here is function which I want to create:

```
public List<T> CreateList<T>()
{
    return new List<T>();
}
```

Here is program, which should create assembly with `DemoType` class, which will contain mentioned `CreateList` method, generated dynamically:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

class GenericMethodBuilder
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var asmName = new AssemblyName("DemoMethodBuilder1");
        var demoAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        var demoModule = demoAssembly.DefineDynamicModule(asmName.Name, asmName.Name + ".dll");
        var demoType = demoModule.DefineType("DemoType", TypeAttributes.Public);

        var create_list_method = demoType.DefineMethod("CreateList", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static);

        var TInput = create_list_method.DefineGenericParameters(new string[] { "TInput" })[0];
        var t_list_type = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(TInput);

        create_list_method.SetParameters(Type.EmptyTypes);
        create_list_method.SetReturnType(t_list_type);

        var ilgen = create_list_method.GetILGenerator();

        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, t_list_type.GetConstructors()[0]);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        Type dt = demoType.CreateType();
        demoAssembly.Save(asmName.Name + ".dll");
    }
}
```

But during execution `create_list_method.GetILGenerator()` I receive `NotSupportedException` at with message:

> Additional information: Specified method is not supported.

What's wrong with this method? I checked out docs, and it seems like ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The received exception is:

> [System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.]
>      at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilderInstantiation.GetConstructors(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
>      at GenericMethodBuilder.Main() :line 26

at the `GetConstructor` call.

This happens because you try to get the constructor of a not yet constructable type `List<TInput>`.

The way to go is to use the magic of the static `TypeBuilder.GetConstructor`-method to create a appropriate representation of the generics type constructor:

`ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(t_list_type, typeof(List<>).GetConstructors()[0]));`

The msdn entry for [TypeBuilder.GetConstructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145822(v=vs.110).aspx) provides a quite extensive explanation as well as examples.

Comment: Oh, Thanks, it fixed my problem